# React error not a function even with me console logging the value?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, state

I am a beginner working on his first MERN project, I created an API for music, added artist, album,... and I have mongo db in the backend and I am having a full crud app with google firebase authentication, the problem is I decided to use audio db API to be able to have a bigger library and to implement more functionality at more ease, I can fetch the API and console log the results but in react when I decide to map it I get the not a function error or cannot map undefined, for both errors prior to writing the code I had console logged both value and it was a valid one. I am also having an issue with authentication that is causing me to not be able to display any information on page load and this is why I decided to go with the API so that way I won't miss with the authentication functions and I can just fetch data for now and later on start pushing to mongo db but I need to display any data on screen first. any ideas what might be wrong ??!
this is the code for my component only
git hub frontend: https://github.com/moeabraham/proj3
git hub backend: https://github.com/moeabraham/proj3-backend

```
    function AlbumSlide ()  {

    const [initData, setInitData] = useState({
        results: ['']
      })
      useEffect(()=> {

          async function getInitData(){
              
            const init = await fetch('https://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/523532/searchalbum.php?s=eminem').then(res => res.json())
    
            setInitData(albums =>({
              ...albums,
              init
            }))
            // console.log(init)
            console.log(initData.init.album)

        
          }
          getInitData()

        
    
      },[])


      

    return  ( 
      <>
      <div className="albumSlide">     
         {initData.init.albums.map((album, idx)=>{
           <p key={idx}>{album.strAlbum}</p>
         })}
</div>

      {/* <section className="albumSlide">
                  <article class="card"  key={idx}> 

      </section> */}
      
      </>
      )
}    


    
export default AlbumSlide;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to guard the access to the `state` value, which takes some time to set (ajax is async, setter is async)

Try something like this in your returned `jsx`

```js
return  ( 
  <>
    <div className="albumSlide">     
      {initData?.init?.albums && initData.init.albums.map((album, idx) =>
        <p key={idx}>{album.strAlbum}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  </>
)
```